# The meaning of 'In the six years since the contract was first awarded'

Tags: meaning, expressions

I am a student learning English.

I read an article and found the expression 'In the six years since the contract was first awarded'

but i was confused about what does mean,

ex)

1. contract was first awarded 6 years ago
   or
2. for 6 years, since the contract first awarded

which one is a right thing?

Thanks all

Comment: It might help people create explanations if you include more context for the sentence fragment that you are asking about.

Comment: I'm confident it's option 1. Note that it's possible the original contract was for a shorter period but that it was renewed, so the six years could be three plus three or whatever.

Comment: The two statements in the question are not mutually exclusive. It means *both* of those things.